# Should I use a colon or semicolon in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

The soup tasted odd, though Mark couldn’t pinpoint exactly why. Like when someone had spat in your food(:)(;) you knew something was off with the taste, texture, or temperature, but not exactly what.

Some people told me colons are better for lists, so the semicolon is a better choice. Is this the case? Why or why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colon is preferable here because what comes after the colon (in your sentence) actually expands on and explains what came before -- that is what a colon is usually expected to do. In short, the colon answers the unspoken questions relating to the first part of the sentence: what, how or why!

Another couple of examples --

"He has the qualities of a perfect gentleman: (what?) chivalry, valor and extreme discretion!"

"This is a perfectly cooked curry: (why? Because it is) well balanced, not too spicy, and VERY flavorful!"

"He played the part, for her, of the perfect husband: (why or how?) he never contradicted her!"

The semicolon, on the other hand, is used to break up a sentence in a different way: unlike with a colon,  the two parts of the sentence (separated by the semi-colon) are not always linked in the form of expansion, enumeration or explanation.

Examples:

It was raining outside; but inside it was warm and very cosy.

He gave her no reply;  in retrospect it seemed an error.

They were drunk on Saturdays; and they regretted it with a splitting headache on the Sunday.

In short, the semicolon creates a convenient PAUSE in the sentence - this pause being longer than a comma and shorter than a full stop - which enables the writer to make some pertinent point; the reader uses it to mentally pause for half a beat in the reading of the sentence.

Comment: Struck and White would agree with the choice of a colon.